# QGIS Python Scripting - Syntax definition

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

After playing around with the QGIS Modeler and looking at the python scripts of what I make, I noticed some syntax which I can't find the definition anywhere. Here is a snippet of the python script from a model:

```
outputs_13=processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", outputs_12['SAVENAME'], ID, 1, 10, 0, True, $rownum , None)
outputs_14=processing.runalg("qgis:deletecolumn", outputs_13['OUTPUT_LAYER'], longitude, None)
outputs_15=processing.runalg("qgis:deletecolumn", outputs_14['SAVENAME'], latitude, savename_alg15)
outputs_16=processing.runalg("qgis:clip", outputs_15['SAVENAME'], vectorlayer_layer1, None)
outputs_17=processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", outputs_16['OUTPUT'], Score, 0, 10, 0, True, 2, output_layer_alg17)
```

Can someone please explain the purpose of ['SAVENAME'], ['OUTPUT'] and ['OUTPUT_LAYER']?

I am trying to develop a script but keep getting errors linked to these terms and I am unsure as to how they are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Using processing algorithms from the console](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html?highlight=processing)

```
import processing 
processing.alghelp("qgis:fieldcalculator")
 ALGORITHM: Field calculator
  INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
  FIELD_NAME <ParameterString>
  FIELD_TYPE <ParameterSelection>
  FIELD_LENGTH <ParameterNumber>
  FIELD_PRECISION <ParameterNumber>
  NEW_FIELD <ParameterBoolean>
  FORMULA <ParameterString>
  OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>

      FIELD_TYPE(Field type)
     0 - Float
     1 - Integer
     2 - String
     3 - Date
processing.alghelp("qgis:deletecolumn")
ALGORITHM: Delete column
LAYERNAME <ParameterVector>
COLUMN <ParameterTableField from LAYERNAME>
SAVENAME <OutputVector>
...
```