# Getting Output names of Processing algorithms via PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, saga, orfeo-toolbox

Calling the results of Processing algorithms in order to plot them to the screen differs depending on the provider used.

An example with QGIS provider:

```
tmpggis = processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer",vektor,"EPSG:4326",None)
out = tmpggis["OUTPUT"]
qgisLyr = QgsRasterLayer(out, "Orfeo")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(qgisLyr)
```

So, for QGIS it is: ["OUTPUT"]    - capital letters

For GRASS it is: ["output"]   - lower case letters

What is the Output name for other providers such as Orfeo Toolbox, SAGA, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may also depend on the algorithm. For example, the `Ordinary Kriging` from SAGA returns two outputs (`VARIANCE` and `PREDICTION`), but other SAGA algorithm outputs are called `OUTPUT`. So, you cannot just use a single output name for all algorithms in a provider.

However, there is a way to get output parameter names from any Processing algorithm. We can define the following function (for instance in the QGIS Python console):

```
import processing

def getAlgOutputNames( algName ):
    for output in processing.Processing.getAlgorithm(algName).outputs:
        print output.name
```

You can call the function in this way, giving it algorithm names you're interested in:

```
>>> getAlgOutputNames("grass7:v.surf.idw")
output
>>> getAlgOutputNames("qgis:creategrid")
OUTPUT
>>> getAlgOutputNames("saga:ordinarykriging")
PREDICTION
VARIANCE
>>> getAlgOutputNames("gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon")
OUTPUT_LAYER
>>> getAlgOutputNames("lidartools:lasmerge")
OUTPUT_LASLAZ
>>> getAlgOutputNames("taudem:dinfinityavalancherunout")
-rz
-dfs
>>>getAlgOutputNames("otb:radiometricindices")
-out
```

*Note: Remember that you can get algorithm names calling `processing.alglist()` from the QGIS Python console.*

Comment: Great answer, I remember asking a somewhat similar question a while ago: [QGIS Python Scripting - Syntax definition](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98330/qgis-python-scripting-syntax-definition).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its really great! The output name for an OTB algorithm I´ve add to the list.

Comment: Don't really understand why @midavalo rejected your edit. I asked you (N'ya) to let me know the outcome of the command in your environment, and I find much better a direct post edit than another answer or a comment. The edit actually complements the answer and let other people know outcomes for different scenarios.

Comment: @ German Carrillo: I guess the edit has been accepted now. And I completely agree with your comment, this gathering of direct post edits is better than new answers.

Comment: @N'ya your edit was rejected, I added your example into the answer. Thanks!