# (pyqgis) How to get temp object created by the processing tool "qgis:saveselectedfeatures"

Tags: pyqgis

Usually when I try to get object:

```
buffering = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', in_layer, 100, 10, False, None)
buf_layer = processing.getObject(buffering['OUTPUT'])
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(buf_layer)
```

But when I do the following it does not work:

```
saving = processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', in_layer, None)
output_layer = processing.getObject(saving['OUTPUT'])
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
```

The error is

```
KeyError: 'OUTPUT'
```

Anyone knows how to get this object?

Comment: This may be what you need: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213564/getting-output-names-of-processing-algorithms-via-pyqgis/213613#213613 Not all algorithms generate outputs with the same name, although you can discover what name is given to each output. For instance, for the algorithm you're using, you'll get 'OUTPUT_LAYER'.